# when can an assignment fail to properly show in Visual C?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

C++ compiled (from the same source) DLL with Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express on both a 64 bit Windows 7 and 32 bit Windows XP.  External 64 bit app on windows 7 calls the DLL and executes properly.  Equivalent 32 bit app on Windows XP bombs on return from DLL call with stack or memory corruption.

Trying to debug this I put a breakpoint where the DLL is copying the data from some internal structures to what the external app wants, last step before returning.  At a given point I'm looking at something like this in Visual Studio:
  destination[i].field = source[i].field;
where both fields in the source and destination are doubles or longs.

Hovering over the source it shows the correctly computed values.  Hovering over the destination, before executing the statement, shows that it was properly initialized to zeros. After executing the statement the destination contain a different value, e.g. 36.3468 becomes 0.00104800000000122891, 6 becomes 10, etc.

This is strange.  Maybe there is a structure element misalignment, but wouldn't that show up as a warning somewhere else?  Maybe I'm stepping over memory (in the 32 bit version only!?), but then shouldn't the value be apparently correct after stepping over the assignment?  Haven't stepped into machine code in a while and don't know x86/x86_64 assembly that well, do I have to do that to see what the code that does that assignment is really doing?

---

Here is one of the lines that seems to not execute properly and the disassembly in both the 64 bit and 32 bit versions, in that order:

```
    destination[i].field  = source[i].field;
000007FEEF6B4DD3  movsxd      rax,dword ptr [i]
000007FEEF6B4DDB  imul        rax,rax,4A68h
000007FEEF6B4DE2  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [i]
000007FEEF6B4DEA  imul        rcx,rcx,30h
000007FEEF6B4DEE  mov         rdx,qword ptr [destination]
000007FEEF6B4DF3  mov         r8,qword ptr [source]
000007FEEF6B4DF8  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [r8+rax+4A40h]
000007FEEF6B4E02  movsd       mmword ptr [rdx+rcx+8],xmm0

    destination[i].field  = source[i].field;
09E64361  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]
09E64364  imul        eax,eax,4A38h
09E6436A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [i]
09E6436D  imul        ecx,ecx,2Ch
09E64370  mov         edx,dword ptr [destination]
09E64373  mov         esi,dword ptr [source]
09E64376  fld         qword ptr [esi+eax+4A10h]
09E6437D  fstp        qword ptr [edx+ecx+4]
```

If I step over that line in the 64 bit version, VS shows me the proper value for destination[i].field, but not in the 32 bit version.  Seems that the structures have different sizes in different versions, thus different offsets and 4 vs 8 bytes in the last assignment, but shouldn't at that point VS show me the proper value?

---

If I step over the fld instruction on the 32 bit version, I can see that st0 is loaded with the wrong value, i.e. not what is shown for source[i].field, For i=0, eax=0, esi=source, thus probably the 4A10h offset is wrong and/or differently computed in the code and what VS uses to show me the value. How is this possible?

Comment: It is not really clear what is going on. Posting code, screenshot, etc might help.

Comment: Different calling conventions, allocating memory with one allocator and deleting it with a different one, etc.

Comment: Many things could cause a misalignment (check your /Zp flag for starters) - certainly any use of pointers in any persisted data structure would be 8 bytes in x64 vs. 4 bytes.  I suggest also trying your 32-bit app on the Windows 7 system to get another data point.  You may also want to try debugging with the debug CRT heap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19f56tw3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I put a breakpoint on a line that reads like above, i.e. destination[i].field = source[i].field.  When the breakpoint hits, destination[i].field is zero, source[i].field is e.g. 36.3468.  Then I hit F10 and look at destination[i].field and the value is 0.001048...!  There is no allocation or deallocation in between, just the wrong value shows up on destination...

Comment: Just try to post a code snippet or better a SSCCE. When the breakpoint is hit, open the disassembly view and post the next ten lines of assembler code.